# atlas-run build failure after timeout error pinging "*/cargocpc/index.html" due proxy authentication required 407

Tags: maven, proxy, confluence, atlas, atlassian-plugin-sdk

While running `atlas-run -dhttp.proxyhost=*...` i get the timeout error after 600000ms (10m). During this 10 minutes everything works fine and i can use my plugin properly. The company where i work use Proxy and therefore i have 2 proxy entries: the first one is in `mvn.bat` and the second one is in `.m2\settings.xml`.
The system was working properly without this problem on windwos 8 but since win 10 i can only use it for 10 minutes.

So what happens exactly:
`atlas-run -X` shows me that maven pings `http://localhost:1990/cargocpc/index.html` but doesnt get the answer

```
[DEBUG] [URLDeployableMonitor] Checking URL [http://localhost:1990/cargocpc/index.html] for status using a timeout of [600000] ms...
[DEBUG] [URLDeployableMonitor] URL [http://localhost:1990/cargocpc/index.html] is not responding: 407 Proxy Authentication Required
[DEBUG] [URLDeployableMonitor] Notifying monitor listener [org.codehaus.cargo.container.spi.deployer.DeployerWatchdog@b272860]
```

and after 600000ms it shuts down.

If i enter this URL in the adress bar from my browser i get the answer: `"Cargo Ping Component used to verify if the container is started."`. Apparently i can connect and see the page but the sdk not.

After 10 minutes i get standard `MojoExecutionException`

```
[INFO] [yer.DeployerWatchdog] Deployable [http://localhost:1990/cargocpc/index.html] failed to finish deploying within the timeout period [600000]. The Deployable state is thus unknown.
[WARNING] [talledLocalContainer] org.codehaus.cargo.container.ContainerException: Deployable [http://localhost:1990/cargocpc/index.html] failed to finish deploying within the timeout period [600000]. The Deployable state is thus unknown.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 10:38 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-12-07T15:58:08+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 36M/355M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.atlassian.maven.plugins:maven-amps-dispatcher-plugin:5.0.13:run (default-cli) on project schuecoPlugin: Unable to execute mojo: Execution null of goal org.codehaus.cargo:cargo-maven2-plugin:1.4.7:start failed: Deployable [http://localhost:1990/cargocpc/index.html] failed to finish deploying within the timeout period [600000]. The Deployable state is thus unknown. -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal com.atlassian.maven.plugins:maven-amps-dispatcher-plugin:5.0.13:run (default-cli) on project schuecoPlugin: Unable to execute mojo
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:216)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:108)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:76)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:116)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:361)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:155)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:584)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:213)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:157)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Unable to execute mojo
        at org.twdata.maven.mojoexecutor.MojoExecutor.executeMojoImpl(MojoExecutor.java:174)
        at org.twdata.maven.mojoexecutor.MojoExecutor$ExecutionEnvironmentM3.executeMojo(MojoExecutor.java:476)
        at org.twdata.maven.mojoexecutor.MojoExecutor.executeMojo(MojoExecutor.java:75)
        at com.atlassian.maven.plugins.ampsdispatcher.AbstractAmpsDispatcherMojo.execute(AbstractAmpsDispatcherMojo.java:60)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:133)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
        ... 19 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Unable to execute mojo
        at org.twdata.maven.mojoexecutor.MojoExecutor.executeMojoImpl(MojoExecutor.java:174)
        at org.twdata.maven.mojoexecutor.MojoExecutor$ExecutionEnvironmentM3.executeMojo(MojoExecutor.java:476)
        at com.atlassian.maven.plugins.amps.MavenGoals.executeMojoExcludeProductCargoConfig(MavenGoals.java:835)
        at com.atlassian.maven.plugins.amps.MavenGoals.startWebapp(MavenGoals.java:918)
        at com.atlassian.maven.plugins.amps.product.AbstractWebappProductHandler.startApplication(AbstractWebappProductHandler.java:71)
        at com.atlassian.maven.plugins.amps.product.AbstractProductHandler.start(AbstractProductHandler.java:61)
        at com.atlassian.maven.plugins.amps.RunMojo.startProducts(RunMojo.java:153)
        at com.atlassian.maven.plugins.amps.RunMojo.doExecute(RunMojo.java:115)
        at com.atlassian.maven.plugins.amps.AbstractProductHandlerMojo.execute(AbstractProductHandlerMojo.java:750)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:133)
        at org.twdata.maven.mojoexecutor.MojoExecutor.executeMojoImpl(MojoExecutor.java:172)
        ... 24 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution null of goal org.codehaus.cargo:cargo-maven2-plugin:1.4.7:start failed: Deployable [http://localhost:1990/cargocpc/index.html] failed to finish deploying within the timeout period [600000]. The Deployable state is thus unknown.
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:144)
        at org.twdata.maven.mojoexecutor.MojoExecutor.executeMojoImpl(MojoExecutor.java:172)
        ... 34 more
Caused by: org.codehaus.cargo.container.ContainerException: Deployable [http://localhost:1990/cargocpc/index.html] failed to finish deploying within the timeout period [600000]. The Deployable state is thus unknown.
        at org.codehaus.cargo.container.spi.deployer.DeployerWatchdog.watch(DeployerWatchdog.java:111)
        at org.codehaus.cargo.container.spi.AbstractLocalContainer.waitForCompletion(AbstractLocalContainer.java:353)
        at org.codehaus.cargo.container.spi.AbstractLocalContainer.start(AbstractLocalContainer.java:231)
        at org.codehaus.cargo.maven2.ContainerStartMojo.executeLocalContainerAction(ContainerStartMojo.java:96)
        at org.codehaus.cargo.maven2.ContainerStartMojo.doExecute(ContainerStartMojo.java:63)
        at org.codehaus.cargo.maven2.AbstractCargoMojo.execute(AbstractCargoMojo.java:432)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:133)
        ... 35 more
[ERROR]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

I hope you can help me.

Answer (score 1):

My mistake was that i forgot to write the nonProxyHosts in `.m2\settings.xml`

```
<proxies>
    <proxy>
      <id>myproxy</id>
      <active>true</active>
      <protocol>http</protocol>
      <host>proxy.somewhere.com</host>
      <port>8080</port>
      <username>proxyuser</username>
      <password>somepassword</password>
      <nonProxyHosts>*.google.com|ibiblio.org</nonProxyHosts>
    </proxy>
  </proxies>
```